# About shift operator trick in C++?

Tags: c++

When I was reading the code in Google Protocol Buffers, I found confused code as follows.

```
1 < 2 ? (void)0 : cout << "hi" << endl;
```

The point is that the string "hi' will pipe through NULL by the left shift operator. As a result, nothing happened. That means this is correct code grammatically.

And I tried out little bit different code as below.

```
(void)0 << "hi" << endl;
```

Of course, It didn't work.

Lastly, I tried out this code.

```
string tmp;
cin >> (1 < 2 ? 0 : tmp);
```

It was compiled but crashed in runtime. (It works if the sign is changed inversely but the input is not stored in tmp.)

Is there someone who can walk me though what to happen in the first case? (in terms of compiler or low level if possible)

Answer (score 5):

You're misreading it, `1 < 2 ? (void)0 : cout << "hi" << endl;` translates to :

```
if(1 < 2) {
    (void)0; //do nothing
} else {
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}
```

`condition ? true-state : false-state;` is called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a), it absolutely has nothing to do with `<<`.

Comment: The key point here is that << has a higher [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) than ?:.

Comment: @OneOfOne Of course it has something to do with `<<`.  If you picked a different operator with lower precedence (e.g. `,`), then it would be evaluated quite differently.

Comment: The ternary operator (`?`) has a special rule where the parts between the `:` are evaluated without regards to normal operator precedence.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan But that's not the case here.  The ambiguous expression is not between the `?` and `:`.

Comment: @jamesdlin maybe prove your point by posting a test case instead of downvoting?

Comment: @OneOfOne `condition ? 1 : 2, 3` is parsed as `(condition ? 1 : 2), 3`, not as `condition ? 1 : (2, 3)` as you seem to be claiming.

Comment: @jamesdlin You're right about my comment. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

[`<<` has higher precedence than `?:`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so:

```
 1 < 2 ? (void)0 : cout << "hi" << endl;
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
(1 < 2) ? (void)0 : (cout << "hi" << endl);
```

*not* to:

```
 ((1 < 2 ? (void)0 : cout)) << "hi" << endl;
```

(And, of course `condition ? then_expression : else_expresion` won't evaluate `else_expression` at all if `condition` is true.)

Answer (score 1):

```
1 < 2 ? (void)0 : cout << "hi" << endl;
```

The other answers have pointed out that the operator precedence gives this a different meaning from what you assumed, so the above is equivalent to:

```
(1 < 2)
    ? (void)0
    : (cout << "hi" << endl);
```

But it's still illegal.

If the second or third operand of the `?:` conditional operator is of type `void`, then the other must also be of type `void` *or* must be a throw-expression.

Casting the third operand to `void` would address that:

```
1 < 2 ? (void)0 : (void)(cout << "hi" << endl);
```

If you can update your question to show the *exact* code you're asking about, we can probably explain it better.

It would also be interesting to see the context in which this appears. By itself, it would be much more legible as an `if` statement.